# How can I get the security group id associated with an ec2 instance using ansible

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to get the security group id associated with EC2 instance using **Ansible**.

It is available in **ec2_facts** however, the variable name contains `"-"` separated MAC address which is giving me problems.

Not sure how to get that information. Any one please?

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: What exactly are you getting? Can you post the output? I get only the security group when I tried.

Comment: I'm trying to add new security group to an instance, first I create a new security group using 'ec2_group' and then (because I didn't get any Ansible way to add new security group in a running instance) adding the security group using AWS CLI and 'raw' module.
Problem I'm facing is I have to get the existing security group id first so that I can pass the existing IDs and new one to aws modify-instance-attribute. If I pass only the new one it removes the old ones.

Comment: ok. You still didn't answer my question. What are you getting as security group from ec2_facts. You mentioned it has some extra chars. Post the value you are getting or a section of the output of ec2_facts

Comment: When I call ec2_facts I get something like:
"ansible_ec2_network_interfaces_macs_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_security_group_ids": "sg-XXXXXXX",
where xx_xx_xx_xx_xx_xx is mac address of machine.

Comment: I can get the security group name but not sec group id (easily).

Comment: Check my solution, you may want to refine it further, but it does get the group ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out:

```
- set_fact:
    myval: "{{item['value']}}"
  when: item.key.find('security_group_ids') != -1
  with_dict: "{{facts.ansible_facts}}"
```

Thanks again for your help! You saved me a lot of time!!

Comment: Another related problem, when there are more than one security groups attached it returns "sg-xxxxxxxx\nsg-xxxxxxxx".
if it would have been ',' instead of '\n' life would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of crude, but does the job.

```
  - name: Gather facts
    action: ec2_facts
    register: facts
  - set_fact: sg={{ item.value | regex_replace('\n', ',') }}
    when: item.key | search("security_group_ids")
    with_dict: facts.ansible_facts
  - debug: var=sg
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!
just one thing, how can I store the extracted value in a separate variable to use further?

Comment: Just figured it out.

Comment: I had to make a minor tweak to get this working with ansible v2.2.0.0: `with_dict: "{{ facts.ansible_facts }}"`.